# how to increase/decrease contrast of a bitmap using MFC?

Tags: c++

how to increase/decrease contrast of a bitmap using MFC?

Answer (score 1):

I think this project may suit your needs:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/imagepreview.aspx